# How to compare this double value to find the result?

Tags: android

Its not working. Here is the code for my Activity.
Is it all write? causez the value of result is not working in the if else statement!!

```
package com.android.don.myapplication;

public class mapActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    }

    public void checkButtonClicked(View view)
    {
        RadioButton maleRadioButton, femaleRadioButton;
        EditText height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText weight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        TextView show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView);
        float h,w;
        double result;
        maleRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleRadio);
        femaleRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleRadio);
        if (maleRadioButton.isChecked()) {
            h = Float.parseFloat(height.getText().toString());
            w = Float.parseFloat(weight.getText().toString());
            result = (h/((w*0.025)*(w*0.025)));
            Toast.makeText(mapActivity.this,"Answer is "+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            if (result < 18.500) {
                show.setText("UW");
            }
            else if (result < 25.000) {
                show.setText("NM");
            } else if (result < 30.000) {
                show.setText("OW");
            }
            else if (result>30.000){
                show.setText("VVM");
            }

        }
        else if (femaleRadioButton.isChecked())
        {
            h = Float.parseFloat(height.getText().toString());
            w = Float.parseFloat(weight.getText().toString());
            result = (h/((w*0.025)*(w*0.025)));
            //Toast.setText(mapActivity.this,"Value of a: " + String.valueOf(result),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            if (result < 16.500) {
                show.setText("UW");
            }
            else if (result < 22.000) {
                show.setText("NM");
            } else if (result < 27.000) {
                show.setText("OW");
            } else if (result>30.000){
                show.setText("VVM");
            }
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select A Gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
 }
```

Comment: what result do you become in the Toast message? I mean what is the value of the `result` variable after the mathematical operations?

Comment: It is not showing.. its giving error that double cant be shown in Toast

Answer (score 0):

try to convert all your values to Double, not some of them to be Float and other to be Double and do the following:

```
double h,w, result;

h = Double.parseDouble(height.getText().toString());
w = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
```